# 'TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration' in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, rotation

```
data = [0, 2, 4, 8, 0, 2, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 2, 0]
def drawBoard(): # Making the board into a 2d array
    count = 0
    for i in range(16):
        print(data[i], end = ' ')
        count += 1
        if count == 4:
            print("")
            count = 0
drawBoard()
data = zip(*data[::-1])
data = data[::-1]
for col in range(4):
    count = 0  
    for row in range(4): 
        if data[row*4+col] != 0:
            data[count*4+col] = data[row*4+col]
    for row in range(count, 4):
        data[row*4+col] = 0
data = data[::-1]
data = list(zip(*reversed(data)))
drawBoard()
```

Whenever I run this code, I get this error:

```
TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
```

On this line:

```
data = zip(*data[::-1])
```

I already looked at other people who asked this question and the answers but I can't fix this.

Can someone please tell me why I am getting this error and how I can fix this.

Comment: I dont understand what your trying to do ..

Comment: `zip(*data[::-1])` is equivalent to `zip(0, 2, 2, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 2, 0, 8, 4, 2, 0)`. Is this what you really want?

Comment: I am making a 2048 game and so to shift left I am rotating the 2d array by 90 degrees and then shifting down then rotating -90 degrees

Comment: What did you expect `zip` to do?

Comment: I really don't know. I just found this to rotate the board 90 degrees: `data = zip(*data[::-1])`

Comment: thats a 1d array... not a 2d array ... what are you talking about a 2d array for?

Comment: No my drawBoard funtion makes it into a 2d array

Comment: No, your `drawBoard` function doesn't change anything at all. All it does is print out some values. Your `draw` is still just a plain old flat list at the end.

Comment: Thats not the point of this problem though

Comment: But that _is_ the point of this problem. Trying to `zip(*…)` to transpose a 1D array makes no sense. If you had a 2D array, it _would_ make sense. And you think you have a 2D array, which is why you're confused by your code not working.

Answer (score 3):

Your root problem seems to be that you think your `drawBoard` function is converting `draw` from a 1D array to a 2D array. But it's not. All it does is *print out* a 2D array representation of `draw`, not changing the values at all. At the end of it, you still have just a plain old flat list.

And trying to `zip(*…)` to transpose a 1D array (a list of numbers) makes no sense. If you had a 2D array (a list of lists of numbers), it *would* make sense. And you *think* you have a 2D array, which is why you're confused by your code not working.

So, the obvious solution is to make yourself a list of lists to work with. If you want a function that makes the board into a list of lists, you have to write one—but that's easy. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks) for a variety of ways to chunk or group a list's elements, and pick the one you like. Then:

```
def makeSquare(lst):
    width = int(len(lst) ** .5)
    if width * width != len(lst):
        raise ValueError('List length must be a perfect square')
    return list(chunkifier_that_you_chose(lst, width))
```

---

Now, you can use it as a 2D array, making all of the rest of your code a whole lot simpler:

```
board = makeSquare(data)

def drawBoard(board):
    for row in board:
        for col in row:
            print(col, end = ' ')
        print()

drawBoard(board)
flippedBoard = zip(*board[::-1])
drawBoard(flippedBoard)
```

---

If you really want to keep the list flat, but flip it with `zip(*…)`, you can squarify it, flip it, then flatten it again:

```
board = makeSquare(data)
flippedBoard = zip(*board[::-1])
flat = [col for row in flippedBoard for col in row]
```

---

As a side note, since you keep talking about arrays, and trying to *use* your lists as arrays, have you considered using [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/)? Even if you wanted to keep everything flat for some reason, NumPy lets you get a reshaped view of the same data (without copying anything around, just making a new "viewer" handle), which you can operate on a lot more easily:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array(data)
data.reshape(4, 4) # as a 2D array
data.reshape(4, 4)[::-1] # reversed
data.reshape(4, 4)[::-1].T # reversed and transposed
data.reshape(4, 4)[::-1].T.reshape(16) # reversed, transposed, back to 1D
```

Comment: Yes I considered NumPy but i wanted to do this without importing anything but random

Comment: Btw what is a chunkifier?

Comment: @Nexus It's a function that chunks or groups a list's elements, that you chose out of the examples from the linked question. You can use the `chunks` function from the first answer, or the `grouper` recipe from the `itertools` docs, or the different `chunks` function from the third answer, or `array_split` from numpy, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what your code is *trying* to do at that point, but `data[::-1]` results in:

```
[0, 2, 2, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 2, 0, 8, 4, 2, 0]
```

which, when passed with `*` to `zip` is equivalent to calling

```
zip(0, 2, 2, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 2, 0, 8, 4, 2, 0)
```

So the first argument to `zip` is `0` and since `zip` expects iterables for all of its arguments, you get a type error.

Comment: How do I fix this

Comment: It depends on what your code is trying to do, which is unclear. What do you want the end result of that line to be?

Comment: i want data = [0, 2, 4, 8, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2]

Comment: To the downvoter: why? I answered part of the question that asked for the source of the error?

Comment: @Nexus - where does that extra `4` come from?

Comment: Which extra 4??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174610/discussion-between-alex-reinking-and-nexus).